# Checker framework cant resolve symbol<annotatedJdk>${org.checkerframework:jdk8:jar}</annotatedJdk> issue

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, checker-framework

Im trying to add Checker Framework via Maven repository i followed checker framework manual [steps](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#maven) but i got this error on intelij ide

[image: Cannot resolve symbol]

someone else mentioned having same issue on [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/checker-framework-dev/cHxKukuXfRs) please any help is appreciated

my maven package is like this

```
  <properties>
    <annotatedJdk>${org.checkerframework:jdk8:jar}</annotatedJdk>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerArguments>
              <Xmaxerrs>10000</Xmaxerrs>
              <Xmaxwarns>10000</Xmaxwarns>
            </compilerArguments>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <path>
                <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
              </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessors><annotationProcessor>org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker</annotationProcessor>
            </annotationProcessors>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-AprintErrorStack</arg>
              <arg>-Xbootclasspath/p:${annotatedJdk}</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>properties</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>8</source>
                  <target>8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

tell me if miss any steps it also does not allow deleting that line with error

Comment: In the docs are described two steps you are at step 2 but seemed to be missing Step 1...meaning adding the appropriate dependencies in the pom file...

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible test case or MWE?  You gave only a partial pom.xml file, no source code, and didn't indicate the command you ran. 
 This makes it hard to understand your problem.

Comment: @mernst stackoverflow does not let me post all POM without writing more explanation so i crop the important parts and an other problem is my code runs without any error it just display this "cant resolve this symbol" issue and when i try something like `method(int array @ArrayLen ( 9 )[])` - > `method(new int[0])` it compiles without any errors

Comment: You can give a link to a repository that contains all the code (preferably with a branch before you started changing it to run the Checker Framework, and another branch that shows your work).  Or you could link to a zip file with those contents.  If you are not willing to show your full code, others cannot debug it (no matter how much they want to help you).

Comment: whole project is here [github link](https://github.com/OmerKayaa/Sudoku) @mernst

Comment: Thanks for the repository link.  I was able to run `mvn -B package` successfully, so maybe this is an IntelliJ problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the project is built by Maven from command line correctly, this looks like IntelliJ IDEA highlighting issue: [IDEA-129269](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129269)/[IDEA-187553](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187553).

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to avoid this issue is to declare the properties as follows:

```
<checkerframework.version>2.5.6</checkerframework.version>
<annotatedJdk>${settings.localRepository}/org/checkerframework/jdk8/${checkerframework.version}/jdk8-${checkerframework.version}.jar</annotatedJdk>
```

Then re-import the Maven project.

Also note that with this it may not be necessary to configure the `maven-dependency-plugin` either.